# PC freezing when updating grub-efi-amd64

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I have installed a kali linux copy from 2021 and didn't update it until today, mid update xfce reloaded after update and pulled up a compatibility problem so i rebooted my PC. Then kali Linux worked flawlessly but i still wanted to continue my update.

Of course, after i shut down my pc it interrupted the installation so i had to do
`sudo apt --fix-missing install`
Again, it started to fix the broken packages until it reached the "grub-efi-amd64" package than it froze at
`Installing for x86_64-efi platform`

I didn't really understand why would it mess with the UFI, since kali linux and grub boot perfectly.

So, can't i skip the grub-efi-amd64 package, ignore it or trick apt that its already updated?

Here's some info that might help:
-its an acer aspire PC (i heard a lot of things about their annoying incompatibility with Linux)
-4GB of RAM (i don't think ram is the problem i even made some swap storage)
-Windows/Kali Linux dual boot.

I have already tried setting the package as manually installed and putting it on hold (using apt) but nothing changed.

That's it send help pls.
(and if you're gonna say if you don't understand Kali Linux don't use it, switch to Ubuntu or upgrading is unnecessary please don't cuz that's so useless)

Thank you

EDIT: i already disabled Windows fast boot so kali has total access to the drives.

Here's the output of some commands you may find useful:

```
┌──(azizbg㉿localhost)-[~]
└─$ efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* USB HDD: Generic Flash Disk   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x15,0x0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x78d3d2,0x800,0xf3b800)RC
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,9ca61072-663b-4c54-9198-bccb2732699e,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0002* debian        HD(2,GPT,9ca61072-663b-4c54-9198-bccb2732699e,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi)
Boot0003* kali  HD(2,GPT,9ca61072-663b-4c54-9198-bccb2732699e,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\kali\grubx64.efi)
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,9ca61072-663b-4c54-9198-bccb2732699e,0xfa000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\kali\grubx64.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000033000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot2001* EFI USB Device        RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
                                                                                                                                                             
┌──(azizbg㉿localhost)-[~]
└─$ lsblk -o +PARTUUID
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
                                           PARTUUID
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk           
├─sda1   8:1    0   499M  0 part           93ff9109-4a5e-4db5-a2f2-5643d8ad0445
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi 9ca61072-663b-4c54-9198-bccb2732699e
├─sda3   8:3    0    16M  0 part           904ebc32-9dfd-4873-a341-cf43b8432521
├─sda4   8:4    0   345G  0 part           a5735859-c9d3-4028-9b20-c7a310dda8e5
├─sda5   8:5    0   326G  0 part           36aa181f-c090-4ad8-81cc-a8da2da1c5cb
├─sda6   8:6    0  65.8G  0 part /         b86598e5-a35f-49ee-89d6-e24077befae0
├─sda7   8:7    0   977M  0 part [SWAP]    490bd7dc-b489-4ec1-b423-4bfab187349d
├─sda8   8:8    0  92.7G  0 part           9079fbc2-f69c-4d70-8cd2-3727c1ba29a4
└─sda9   8:9    0   519M  0 part           b16a2015-51c7-4261-b80a-bd4f38631a6a
sdb      8:16   1   7.6G  0 disk           
└─sdb1   8:17   1   7.6G  0 part           0078d3d2-01
```

Comment: *Windows/Kali Linux dual boot* is the problem if the default Windows Fast Startup feature is enabled. Boot Windows, disable it and shutdown. Boot Kali and try again. Also, if you have to ask this question, Kali is NOT for you. It expects experienced Linux users doing pentesting and/or other forensic activities only, it's NOT a normal Linux desktop that can be used as a daily driver.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Huh? Why would fast startup be relevant? I don't think it would/could lock the UEFI NVRAM?

Comment: @TomYan Yes, it can and it occasionally does keep the ESP locked thus inaccessible for this sort of operations that need writing access to it. It doesn't affect the post-POST boot because UEFI has been designed around it since its inception. Among other reasons this is why disabling Fast Startup is a must when dual-booting and even recommended if running Windows standalone.

Comment: @ChanganAuto If you say so. I don't really see how it can "lock" a FAT32-formatted partition. (Besides, even say it set e.g. GPT attribute and it does cause Linux to mount it as read-only, then grub-install should just fail.) As for the UEFI part, the only thing I can think of that fast startup might mess with is `BootNext`, which is not relevant here. I highly doubt that the UEFI spec has even defined a way for an OS to "lock" the NVRAM. I'd say it's more likely some UEFI firmware bug/flaw.

Comment: Recently I saw a post here that seems to show that Debian make grub-install work a bit differently from other distro, namely it would make sure that there is only one debian UEFI boot entry. Since Kali is debian-based, it might be doing the same thing and the resulted action might happen to trigger a bug/flaw in your UEFI firmware, causing the boot entry registration to stall. (You may experiment by running `grub-install` with and without `--removable`.)

Comment: @ChanganAuto i already disable fast boot

Comment: Consider adding the output of `efibootmgr` and `lsblk -o +PARTUUID` to your question.

Comment: @TomYan done, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I have some wild attempts that you may want to try. I do not guarantee that it would help, and **it might completely stop you from being able to boot the Kali installation**.

First of all, see if you can run these successfully:

```
sudo efibootmgr -B -b 0004
sudo efibootmgr -o 0003,0001,2001,2002,2003
```

Then run `efibootmgr` again to see if they at least seem to have effects, i.e., `BootOrder`'s `0004` replaced with `0003`, `Boot0004` gone.

I am not sure if you have rebooted since you cancelled the package update (or if you have cancelled it at all or just left it stalling).

---

If you have never rebooted since the update stalls (and was cancelled), you may want to resume the package update without rebooting at all. If it still doesn't work, consider whether you want to take the risk and reboot. You may not be able to boot back to Kali for numerous reasons.

If you decide to take the risk, check `efibootmgr` again right before you reboot and see if `BootOrder` has been changed (from `0003,0001,2001,2002,2003`). Also check whether `Boot0003` has been changed and whether there's any new entry created. If any of these happen to be true, consider report back first before continue with the reboot decision.

Before you reboot, you may also see if `efibootmgr -B -b 0003` helps in making the update run successfully. But deleting both `Boot0004` and `Boot0003` means very likely (i.e., unless your UEFI firmware actually locks the boot variables and order for reasons) **you will not be able to boot Kali again**, *unless you run this to recreate an entry before you reboot*:

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 2 -l \EFI\kali\grubx64.efi -L kali
```

(You should not run this if the update has worked. Just run `efibootmgr` to check that the update / `grub-install` recreated the entry for you. You may even want to check with `efibootmgr` to see if the *cancelled* update also recreated the entry for you first.)

Double check with `efibootmgr` that the entry has been successfully and correctly (i.e., looks identical to the original `Boot0003`) recreated and added to `BootOrder` (preferably / expectedly, as the first item in the order).

---

If you have rebooted since the update stalls and was cancelled, you may want to just reboot again first. After you rebooted, check if `Boot0004` remains gone or comes back (and/or whether `0003` has been replaced by `0004` in `BootOrder` and `BootCurrent`).

If now you don't see any `0004` in the `efibootmgr` output anymore. Try to resume the package update and see if it still stalls. If it does, consider `efibootmgr -B -b 0003` as written above.

If you see that the `Boot0004` entry comes back as if the deletion was not performed, you may want to check your UEFI settings and see if there's any option that locks the boot variables and/or order. (I only heard of such option in some UEFI settings. Not sure about the exact wording.) If you are able to find it, disable the lock and try the solution above again. (Or perhaps even, just straightly resume the update and see if it now works first.)